# Slot Machine Synth Tone

Tags: sound-design, sound, synthesizer, replication

I'm working on a project which requires me to recreate the sound of an old school slot machine.
If you check out this video at 1:25 you'll hear the sound I mean:

(audio isn't amazing unfortunately)

I think the machine may actually be just playing back WAV audio but I'm not sure, but basically I want to recreate something similar to that tone. I've tried a bunch of stuff, basic synth sounds, bells and chimes and things but can't quite capture that ridiculously pleasant 'round' tone that it has...

Anyone got any ideas? How would you go about trying to recreate this tone?

Thanks!

Comment: not really an answer, as it's 200 bucks [100 for a few days over black weekend] but [Chromaphone](https://www.applied-acoustics.com/chromaphone/overview/) could very likely do what you need. It's a percussive bar/skin modelling synth plugin.

Answer (score 2):

For soft sounds like that, an FM synth would be a good start.
They're next to impossible to program (intentionally) if you don't have an engineering degree, but a lot of presets would suit that tone fine.

Native Instruments FM7 and FM8 are decent paid versions, and there's a DX10 that comes with Fruity Loops.

You might also want to to try layering different sounds, such as the glockenspiel, as mentioned above.

Comment: FM synths aren't THAT hard to program once you learn what all is going on ;) But yes, an glockenspiel or vibraphone preset on an FM synth would be a great starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Glockenspiel would sound quite near to what you would want it to sound like. If you are planning to digitally create it then get a VST insturment for the same and apply filters to get the round tone you want.

Here is a video to show you what it could sound like: